# CSS with Vuetify V-data-table

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am attempting to add some table row spacing in my table. However I am not having much success. I can see my styles when I inspect the page, and they are not crossed out. Any ideas as to why I can't impose styles on my table? I have thoroughly read through some of the other vuetify posts for imposing css, but have had no success. Any thoughts?

**Style:**

```
`<style scoped>
    >>>tr {
        border-spacing: 10px;
        border:none;
    }

</style>`
```

**Photo of console**
[image]

**data table code**

```
<template>
    <v-data-table :headers="headers"
                  :items="posts"
                  :items-per-page="5"
                  hide-default-header
                  item-key="post_id"
                  class="elevation-1 browseTable"
                  :footer-props="{
      showFirstLastPage: true,
      firstIcon: 'mdi-arrow-collapse-left',
      lastIcon: 'mdi-arrow-collapse-right',
      prevIcon: 'mdi-minus',
      nextIcon: 'mdi-plus'
    }">
        <template #item.full_post="{ item }">
            <p>{{ item.title }}</p>
            <p>{{item.body }}</p>
        </template>
    </v-data-table>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply `border-spacing` to `table`, not `tr`. Also need to have `border-collapse: separate;` for this to work. Usually it's set to `separate` as default, but not sure if vuetify overwrites it

```css
>>> table {
  border-spacing: 10px;
  border-collapse: separate;
}
```

As for the `border: none`, I suspect it's set on the `td` level. So if you want to affect that style, do:

```css
>>> table td {
  border: none;
}
```